# contents of file is not read complete

Tags: php, file, fopen

I have a textfile with currently 9130 lines which I read and parse for a keyword. Today I detected that the file is not read complete and I wonder why?

php version: PHP 5.5.9 on ubuntu ( I know it is an old version)

#### Read the textfile with file()

```
private function findTodoOld(  ) {
    $lines = file( $this->localFilename, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );

    $matchedLines = array(  );
    foreach( $lines as $line ) {
        $pattern = '@todo';
        if ( strpos( $line, $pattern ) !== false ) {
            array_push( $matchedLines, $line );
        }
    }
    return $matchedLines;
}
```

#### Read the textfile with fopen()

```
private function findTodo(  ) {
    $matchedLines = array(  );

    $handle = fopen($this->localFilename, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
            if ( strpos( $line, "@todo" ) !== false ) {
                array_push( $matchedLines, $line );
               }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    } 
    return $matchedLines;
}
```

Both approaches get the same result:

- The content of line 9100 is not read complete (and the rest of the file as well)
- If I remove line 9100, then the new line 9100 will as well not read complete (and the rest of the file as well)
- the `$matchedLines` contains 1173 entries.

Running the approach with `fopen` with the same textfile on PHP 7.1.16 (on an OSX) works fine. All lines are read, the `$matchesLines`contains 1187 entries.

My assumption: It has something todo with the memory. At the ubuntu machine php has a memory_limit of 128 M, which looks for me enough to process a textfile.

**Any Idea how I can process the complete content of the file?**

Interessting would be as well how I can analyse why the line 9100 is not read complete.

Comment: look into [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php), i.e don't build an array and return it but instead just `yield` each line from the for loop. almost no memory then

Comment: If you set the binary flag `b` will it work ?

Comment: I could figure out the problem, it was a memory problem, created by a function further in the code. Thanks @LawrenceCherone for your comment. It did not solve my problem, but pointed me in a new direction to solve the problem :)